Nested Routes on top level Routes - nuxt 3
Why do you want to do this thing?
The problem here is that I want to write a layout in it. I can put definePageMeta, for example, middleware or pageTransition, which applies to all pages that contain this layout. But definePageMeta, I think it is for pages?

How do I create Nested Routes, but in top level Routes, for example:
I do not want :
 - /start.vue
 - /call.vue
 - /info.vue <- Here i write a structure that applies to everything in the [info] folder
 - /info
-----/about.vue
-----/beginning.vue
-----/statistics.vue


But I want a way:
 - /{structure}.vue <- Here I write a structure that applies to every file that starts with this file name [structure]
 - /start.vue
 - /call.vue
 - /_structure_about.vue
 - /_structure_beginning.vue
 - /_structure_statistics.vue


As an example only, the word _structure_ will not appear in the link. It only takes the structure from the file called structure.vue
The output will be like this:
 - example.example/start
 - example.example/call
 - example.example/about
 - example.example/beginning
 - example.example/statistics

What I want to apply is the same idea of layout with pages, but the problem with layout is how do I put definePageMeta(middleware) or definePageMeta(pageTransitio) in it that applies to all pages that Use this layout.

So, you want the default layout basically? Put your stuff in there and customize each page with definePageMeta yes. Your page should dictate the layout you want to have. If it's the default, no need to ask for something different so you can skip it. If you want another one, then use definePageMeta yes. As for your routes, it's mostly dynamic routes again. I really feel like we've been edging the thing for days now with the same questions/answers.
